# Download Foursquare Venue Icons

Tags: icons, foursquare

I want to develop an iPhone App with a Map that shoes the foursquare venues with their venue icons. To improve the performance, I will store the venue icons in my app. It is clear to me, that this is not the best way. But if an icon is missing, I can download this and if the icon design is changing, I must update the app.
Is there a place where I can download all the venue icons in one zip?
Best Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no zip file of icons, but you can access information about categories via the /venues/categories endpoint. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories for details

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try to catch all of the icons there.

Comment: @user1611851 have you catched them ? Maybe you'd like to share them? ;)

Comment: What about the associated usage licence? Can't find the info, is it open source?